# Redirecting Dynamic Url to Static Url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic

I have read a lot of suggestion, article but i could not fixed my problem. Here is my Url :

> us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education
>   ja/resources?id=366:video-clip

I want to redirect this URL to static URL. I have tried with .htaccess Like this :

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
>   (/|.php|.html|.htm|.feed|.pdf|.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
>
> RewriteRule (.*) index.php
>
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
>
> Redirect 301
>   /tw/en/investment-opportunities/ultimate-banking-how-to-create-your-own-bank
>   http://takeshiyashima.com/tw/investment-opportunities/ultimate-banking-how-to-create-your-own-bank

Above URL Fixed and working now but the top URL i have mentioned are not working. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, give a more clear example and post the right link, as it is not clear if there is any symbol before 'ja/resources' and if it's a part of the link at all.

As I understand you want to take only the part: 
'my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education'

and redirect to: 'http://takeshiyashima.com/tw/investment-opportunities/my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education'
If it's true here is the possible rule:

us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education

```
RewriteRule ^\/?us/my-blog\?catid=\d+id=\d+\:(.*) http://takeshiyashima.com/tw/investment-opportunities/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Not tested and can be made shorter. If you give more details to the example I will try to help.

**Update according to your comment**

For ja/resources?id=366:video-clip to takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources it is:

```
RewriteRule ^\/?ja/resources.* http://takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources [R=301,L]
```

For 'us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-educatio‌​n', everything is clear, but I see no logic in '/1-my-thought', we have to have a clear pattern. If you say that
you want to take always first 2 words from 'my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-educatio‌​n'
then we can make '/1-my-thought', but if you will have different strings like 'my-stuff-education-is-cool', then we will not be able to apply a pattern using regular expressions. Please, provide more original links (3+) you would like to change, so I can see if there is any pattern.

If there is no pattern at all it is possible to use, for example, RewriteMap for Apache with an additional script on the server side, which will handle your links, but it's a more complex way, so let's stick to regular rewrites for now. Waiting for 3+ more examples.

Comment: I want to change this **us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education** to **/us/my-blog/1-my-thought/404-my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education** and **ja/resources?id=366:video-clip** to **http://www.takeshiyashima.com/ja/resources**

Comment: I have a lot of link with same parameters I want all to redirect in a static page.  
Here are some example URL which I want to channge:  



**1. _us/resources?catid=72&id=354:fractional-reserve-banking_** 

 
**2. _ja/?catid=0&id=711_**  


**3. _ja/resources?id=369:seminar_**

Comment: 'RewriteRule ^\/?us/my-blog\?catid=\d+id=\d+\:(.*) http://takeshiyashima.com/tw/investment-opportunities/$1 [R=301,L]'

This is not Working !

Comment: Here is All the link from my crawl Error report - https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvg3atbdw9aqvy/www-takeshiyashima-com_20140514T075551Z_CrawlErrors.csv ..

Comment: Here is the .htaccess file I'm working      https://www.dropbox.com/s/a718snpi2b3xe3b/.htaccess .   I cant redirect as you suggested through.

Comment: Hi! First of all I would delete everything in your .htaccess and start from scratch as you have many rules that influence one another, also double directives, double RewriteEngine On etc. Start a new .htaccess and add everything step by step with understanding what a rule will do, some rules may overlap and thus cannot work. As to your static URLs, there is no logic right now, so even several rules won't help at all. As a solution (if still not indexed) - make new urls more logical, the destination URL must have values/parts that are present in the original URL, otherwise there is no logic.